# How do I side-load a font in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, electron

Without admin privileges to install a font, how do I use a non-installed font in vscode?  Visual Studio Code is built on Electron, so it should be able to load css, right?

Answer (score 0):

Since Visual Studio Code is built on Electron, it is able to load css, yes.  Modifying vscode-internal files [will cause your title bar to display `[Unsupported]`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/supporting/faq#_installation-appears-to-be-corrupt-unsupported), however.

The avenue for side-loading fonts through css is as follows:

- Download and extract a font.  For this example, [I'm using `Iosevka`](https://github.com/be5invis/Iosevka/releases/tag/v3.4.6) since it comes with a ready-to-use stylesheet already.
- Modify your install's `workbench.js` script found at `resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/workbench/` by appending the following snippet (the path separator used is unimportant; [node.js](/questions/tagged/node.js) will deal with `/` just fine on [windows](/questions/tagged/windows))

```js
const el = document.createElement('style');
el.type = 'text/css';
const content = document.createTextNode(`
@import url('C:/path/to/iosevka.css');
`);
el.appendChild(content);
document.head.appendChild(el);
```

- Configure your `settings.json` to use the font

  ```
    "fontFamily": "'Iosevka Web', monospace",
  ```
- Reload your editor

---

If your font does not have a stylesheet for you to load, you can specify your own `fontFamily` in the above `content` variable:

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Iosevka Web';
    font-display: swap;
    font-weight: 100;
    font-stretch: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    src: url('woff2/iosevka-thin.woff2') format('woff2'),
        url('woff/iosevka-thin.woff') format('woff'),
        url('ttf/iosevka-thin.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

---

One last note, it is possible to load a stylesheet from the Internet, but I kept this answer to local files for simplicity.  It is also possible to run the snippet per-session to avoid persistence, but I didn't see the purpose of doing so and leave it as an exercise to the reader.